# Create Column Allow NULL but Default Value Set to NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Id like to create a column on my table that allows null but is set by default to empty (not `null`)

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} DEFAULT '';
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What type are you specifying? Your query works for me on MySql when using varchar.

Comment: was using text. I'll try varchar

Comment: What symptoms are you seeing? How are you inserting data into the table?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you try

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_tablename_columnname
  BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
  FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.columnname = IFNULL(NEW.columnname, '')
```